# AND vs OR function fallacy

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

Suppose I have a very large population of parts with a known 20% failure rate.
Suppose I randomly select 5 samples and inspect for the known failure.

I calculate that the probability of all five samples passing is
=0.8*0.8*0.8*0.8*0.8=0.328
P( 0.8 ∩ 0.8 ∩ 0.8 ∩ 0.8 ∩ 0.8 ) = 0.328
I believe this is correct.

If I reverse the thought process and ask what is the probability of one sample failing, I do:
=0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 = 1.0
P( 0.2 ∪ 0.2 ∪ 0.2 ∪ 0.2 ∪ 0.2 ) = 1.0
I know this is wrong.

I know using the OR function in this matter is a fallacy, because I know that I would not be guaranteed to find a failure.  What I don't know is WHY?  Why is the OR function incorrect in this case?

Please let me know if you see any other errors in my math.

Note: this is not for homework.  I finished college statistics 12 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ *only if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive.* More generally,
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
with a more general form for finding $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i)$. This is known as the *inclusion-exclusion rule*.

To reverse the process, you can realize that the probability of at least one sample failing is the complement of none of the samples failing (this is one version of *De Morgan's Law*). Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ sample fails.
\begin{align*}
P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots A_5) &= 1 - P((A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_5)^c) \\
&= 1 - P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap \cdots \cap A_5^c) \\
&= 1 - P(A_1^c)P(A_2^c)\cdots P(A_5^c) \\
&= 1 - 0.8^5 = .67232
\end{align*}

As a final comment, you could look into the *Binomial Distribution* for a more flexible approach. Suppose you select $n$ samples, and the pass rate is $p = 0.8$. If $X$ is the number of samples which pass inspection, then $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n, 0.8)$ with probability mass function
$$P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x}\ 0.8^x\ 0.2^{n-x}$$
This general formula allows you to easily answer both questions posed above, as well as any other probability questions you may have.